# Does $i^T=-i$ or $i^T = i$ ?(T is transpose)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, complex-numbers

Assume $A$ is a skew-symmetric matrix(its eigenvalues is zero or purely imaginary). If $x$ is its eigenvector,  we have $$x^TAx=\lambda|x|^2$$, take transpose on both sides. we have $$-x^TAx=(\lambda|x|^2)^T$$

If $\lambda \in \Bbb{R}$,then $\lambda = 0$. If $\lambda$ is purely imaginary, the equation hold if and only if $i^T = -i$. but $i$ is a number, its dimension is $1$. So I think its transpose is itself. what's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula $x^T A x=\lambda |x|^2$ holds for real matrix $A$ and real eigenvector $x$. In that case, there is no reason that $x$ is a real vector. So this formula does not hold.

In the complex case, $x^* Ax=\lambda |x|^2$ holds (if $Ax=\lambda x$ holds,) where $|x|^2=x^*x$ and $x^*$ is [conjugate transpose](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_transpose) of the vector $x$.

Comment: thank you. I have made a mistake. Eigenvector may not real. so must use $x^*Ax$ instead of $x^TAx$, then $(x^*Ax)^* = -x^*Ax = -\lambda |x|^2 = (\lambda |x|^2)^*$